# Drawing canvas size in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, drawing, canvas

I frequently use the drawing canvas to insert and group figures and text.
However, the page size and its margins, size of inserted figures, and figure position change according to type of manual I create. 
Is there a way to set the default size of canvas?
If yes, where is this done and where is it saved to (per document, per connected template, per general template, other)?
Thank you,
Josh

Comment: I couldn't see a way to do it here, but saving various sizes as autotexts (or possibly rich text autocorrect  entries) might be a reasonably simple approach.

Comment: Thank you. Received a similar reply from the Microsoft community forum.   So although odd, that may be the way. Thank you!

Comment: if it turns out to work for you, can you please post an Answer to your own question saying what you did. You should then be able to mark it as The Answer , unless you haven't got enough points or some such.